# Excel SaveAs Dialog

Tags: vba, excel

I have code to have a default name and add a timestamp to it.  That works well.  Now I am trying to create a Save As Dialog that pops up to allow the user to view the new filename and edit the path to save it.  It gives me an error in section 2 below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim sFileName As String
Dim sDateTime As String
Dim txtFileName As String

'0. Set new filename with timestamp.
With ThisWorkbook
    sDateTime = " (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ").xlsm"
    sFileName = "2018 Testy" & sDateTime

'1. Check of Save As was used.
If SaveAsUI = True Then
    Cancel = True

  '2. Call up your own dialog box.  Cancel out if user Cancels in the dialog box.
   txtFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(sFileName, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As XLSM file")
    If txtFileName = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Action Cancelled", vbOKOnly
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

  '3. Save the file.
   Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=txtFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: works for me, just remove the `With ThisWorkbook` from your code

Comment: So, **anytime** the document is saved, instead of giving the choice of name (if "Save As" is clicked) or instead of saving as the current file naame (if "Save" is clicked), you want the file to save with a current date/rtime tag, correct?  So even you won't be able to save as another name.  Is that what you wanted?  Other than what Shai suggested,  You should also go `Cancel = True` no matter what since you're it programmatically., otherwise it will save 2x in a row.  `Cancel=True` tells Access it doesn't have to do anything (that "you haav it under control")

Comment: My intent is that once a user decides to close a file, a dialog pops up that has the time-stamped filename, path and XLSM already populated.  The user can then modify if necessary.  Hope this helps.

Comment: this works for me also. What exactly is the problem? Your code is set up to apply the name if they have chosen Save As...

Comment: In your comment you say "*once a user decides to close a file, a dialog pops up*" If you want that code to run when a workbook gets closed you should use the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event instead of `Workbook_BeforeSave`

Comment: Maybe its because i'm using a mac but the dialog box never pops up for me when i press the cancel button or save button?  I changed it to BeforeClose